# Converting a column of a data frame to series with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

In order to convert the first column of a data frame to a series, I wrote:

```
dict1 = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11],
         'col2': [4, 5, 6, 9, 5, 0],
         'col3': [7, 5, 8, 12, 1,11]
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1)
series5 = df1.ix[:,0]
```

However, Python gives me error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

How can I handle this situation? Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `series5 = df1.ix[:,0]` part with `series5 = df1.iloc[:,0]`, then it started to work, but why it did not work with `dataframe.ix` code?

Comment: because ix is not present in the latest versions of pandas.